# call Action twice in same view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7ET4.png)Hi I have an action that returns partial view I want to call it partial twice from view after once inside a modal and once outside the modal to fit the site to mobile. I use @html.action what actually happens is that there are events on click in partial and the js always listens only to the first and the one I put second inside a modal for example does not work. If I change their order on the page it will be reversed. Looking for a solution how to call that partial.

my code:

@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Cars")

```
    <div class="modal fade carDetielsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    @*<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>*@

                    <img src="~/images/icon_X (1).png" />
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                @Html.Action("Search", "Cars")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Cars")

Comment: It would be more suitable to adapt your modal to a smaller screen first, so it does not render as a modal on mobile devices. Css has got media-queries for that. Start rendering it for the smallest screen size and then adapt for larger ones.

Comment: Thank you. but the requirement here is that mobile will appear inside Modal and desktop will appear outside Modal so media matching will not help me

Comment: The other way around then - the point is: that in my opinion, this is a matter of markup and styling, not rendering a view twice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.